# Correct Situation for use of Simple Past

Tags: past-simple

Where did you go when I came to your home in the morning?

a) I went to the Market .

b) I went to the market when you came to my home.

b1) You came to my home when I went to the market.

c) I had gone to the market when you came to my home.

Which answer is correct?Why?

I Would like to prefer b or b1 because I just want to give him information of being gone to market.

Comment: *I was at the market when you came...* - simple!

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are both alright.

`c` is okay as well, if you had already left by the time that person came to your home.

`b1` is a variant of `b`, but a really weird one since it's highlighting the wrong thing, as though it's trying to answer a different question.

Answer (score -2):

`a` is correct. The verb is at **past tense simple** - `went`- describing an action that happened in the past, and the time is specified `in the morning`.

`c` is correct. The 1st verb is at **past perfect simple** - `had gone` - describing an action that happened before another past action - `you came`.

I would say `b` is not correct since both actions are at **past tense simple**, meaning they would be happening at the same time - which in this case is kind of ambiguous, `i went to the market` - i was leaving the house but then `you came` - which would imply that we met so I didn't actually reached the market because i met you. As @Maulik V♦ commented out, you could say `I was at the market when you came...` which would be perfectly acceptable - both actions could be happening at the same time - `i was at the market` and `you came`.

`b1` is just the same case as `b`, doesn't matter if the phrases have been switched around.